# git for-each-ref not showing default branch

Tags: arrays, bash, git, git-branch

I'm using this command in a bash script to build an array of current local branches:

```
for branch in $(git for-each-ref --no-merged dev --format='%(refname:short)' refs/heads/); do
    branches+=("$branch")
done
```

it returns all my local branches EXCEPT the default branch of the repo. What am I missing?

I have tried various other "patterns" according to the documentation (https://git-scm.com/docs/git-for-each-ref)
including `refs/heads/*` but none return the default branch. I confirmed it doesn't matter what branch I am checked out on, I can't get it to show up in any situation.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: currently, our "default" branch is "dev"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're asking git which branches are *not merged* in `dev`.

It means that only branches with at least one commit **not** on `dev` will show up. `dev` can never be on that list, no matter what.

To get all your branches without filter, just get rid of the conditions :

```
git for-each-ref --format='%(refname:short)' refs/heads/
```

Comment: ok thanks for the this clarification. when I do a "git branch" locally, I get dev AND all the branches that are showing up with the `for-each-ref` command above. why this discrepancy?

Comment: `git branch` outputs all (local) branches. But your `for-each-ref` (plumbing counterpart to `branch` porcelain) is explicitly *restricting* output with `--no-merged dev`. This is why.

Comment: ok thanks, so can I fix that by adding another condition on the end? I know you can have multiple conditions. if I removed the filter `refs/heads/` then I get a ton of branches that I don't want

Comment: What is it you want to get? All branches?

Comment: Ultimately I want the same output as what `git branch` shows on the CLI.

Comment: Just get rid of `--no-merged dev` in your `for-each-ref`

Comment: Now I feel stupid. Thank you. I originally copied this command from somewhere else and clearly didn't study it enough to fully understand what it was doing. I was so focused on the filter condition at the end. Thank you!